# Network connection between two operation systems in a virtual machine

Tags: networking, vmware-workstation

I have a Windows 7 machine with VMware installed on it. I created two separate Windows 2003 Server virtual machines.

I want to establish a network connection between the two virtual machines (Both Windows 2003 Server) through their IP addresses. The IP addresses are `100.100.100.1` and `192.168.10.11`.

**How do I go about this?**

Answer (score 0):

Set the network options to bridged network in both VMs, and specify an IP in the same range i.e. 192.168.10.11 and 192.168.10.12. If the IPs are in a different range you'd need a router. besides 192.168.x.xis for private networks, so that it wouldn't be routed.

Comment: Ya thank u for u r answer but the thing is I should maintain 100.100.100.1 for one os and 192.168.10.11 for another.

Comment: You cannot!! You should use a router, and NAT and setup this for all the services, if possible. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address#IPv4_private_addresses

Answer (score 0):

You will need a router on the network.  with a route that looks something like this:

192.168.10.0  to 100.100.100.0
100.100.100.0 to 192.168.10.0

This will bridge the gap between the two networks.  You cannot do this without a router.  Keep in mind if you have other equipment on the network of 192.168.10.0 the above route will give all equipment access to the server on the 100.100.100.0

Answer (score 0):

### In short

#### On each guest

Create a **second** network adapter

- custom host-to-host network
- DHCP dynamic

#### Create a router

Install a **third** virtual machine and install DHCP router software

- create **second** custom host-to-host network adapter
  (first network adapter is router-host network)
- create unique network ROUTER on second adapter

#### Go back to each guest

Assign **second** adapter on both guests to ROUTER network

#### Be carefull

Read the instructions in the step-by-step manual carefully.

Avoid conflict of two DHCP server running on the same network.

#### Step by Step

An explicit instruction can be found 
[here](http://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-11/topic/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-87995B4F-5945-4AF8-86D1-1003DDEFCF25.html)

Found in the VMware documentation